# Animation jerking on mobile and sometimes not working at all

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to create a different loading animation (revealing content). I managed to get it to work pretty well on the desktop, but it doesn't want to work well on mobiles. On a mobile it will jerk or when it does catch up the animation has completed.

The animation is just 2 divs like this:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader-background"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is like this:

```
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -750px;
  right: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20000px #000000;
  transition: all 3s;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  opacity: 1;
  /* Start off-screen */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I have created this on code pen so you can see it in action:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/rwLagV

Does anyone know of a way I can get this working without having the jerking motion?

Comment: Try to use will-change for transform and opacity https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/. This will involve the GPU, use hardware acceleration.

Comment: Isn't rendering 20000px of shadow spread a bit intensive for mobiles?